# Is there a known way to map all possible analog stick values to buttons?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-gamecube, super-smash-bros-melee

I'm having to develop my own Gamecube controller so I can play Melee without debilitating pain. I can't use an analog stick at all(that's one of the things that aggravates my wrists) and need a way to simulate an analog stick with buttons. Is there a known way to map all analog stick outputs to key presses? I'm open to any ideas you have. If not, I will have to develop a system for it. I can do that, but...I'd prefer not to lol.

EDIT: I looked up some of the smash box controllers, and I might go with the modifier system they use. I was hoping for a system that could emulate all of the available positions an analog stick could be in.

Comment: An analogue stick could theoretically be in more positions than a keyboard has keys for. Unless you want to restrict to only left-right-down-up and the pure diagonals between those, what you ask for is just not possible without a keyboard the size of a desk.

Comment: ...which is actually precisely the case, as a controller using arcade buttons that was made for the same exact reason the question was posted is the side of a large shoebox at the smallest